# background color for <div id = "box"> wont show

Tags: css, html

I'm working on a small project and I've encountered an issue were the background color for a div that I have isn't showing.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html> 
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Hello, World!</title>
            <!--references-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/index.css" />
            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        </head>
            <body>
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id = "box">
                        <h1 id="head">Hello, World!</h1>
                    </div> <!--Box-->
                </div> <!--wrapper-->
            </body>
        <script src="js/Index.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
   font-weight: 300; 
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#Box {
    background-color: #EEE;
    Width: 100px;
    Height: 100px;
}

#head {
    font-size: 15pt;
}
```

I've never had an issue like this and any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Watch your casing, IDs and classes are case-sensitive

Comment: Your "Box" id isn't applied because of casing, as Andrew said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you are using the same case, **classes** and **id's** are case sensitive:

Change `#Box` to `#box`

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7ku7qvfx/12/

```
#box {
    background-color: #EEE;
    Width: 100px;
    Height: 100px;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Case_Sensitivity_in_class_and_id_Names

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions.

Comment: @AndrewL. Please down vote my answer or flag it for removal.